# Struts 2 with convention plugin - ExceptionMapping not working

Tags: struts2, struts

I have the following action which maps java.lang.Exception to a result of name test:

```
@Action(value = "getDispMeiosGruposAmbientes", results = {
    @Result(name = "test", type = "chain", params = {
        "actionName", "getItensSuprimento"
    })}, exceptionMappings = {
    @ExceptionMapping(exception = "java.lang.NullPointerException", result = "test", params = {"param1", "val1"})
})
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        throw new NullPointerException();
//        return "test";
    }
}
```

test result should redirect to a jsp page when an exception is thrown.

But this is not working. Maybe the syntax is wrong?

EDIT: i have changed the action and now i can redirect to an action when i return "test" string, but not when i throw an exception. Everything appears to be ok.

Comment: is it throwing a 500 error, what is the current result that is happening?

Comment: I receive an OK response and nothing happens when the exception is thrown. No console message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that i was using version 2.3.20 of Struts and there was a bug with exception mappings where thrown exceptions are not caught. I have changed to version 2.5.17 and now exception mapping works fine.

This bug is described [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27721814/after-upgrading-to-struts-2-3-20-exception-handling-not-working) and [Apache JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4433);